# EF 5 Update model from oracle database is not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC application using oracle as database. I Used EF 5 database first and when I started I Created Model without any problem. but now when i tried to update model from database it's not working. it shows in update wizard but when i click finish nothing happens. it's not added to .edmx and there is no model classes generated.

- all tables have primary key
- most of Fields are not null
- there is no reserved words

I created table with the same structure of one of the old table who already in the model. but it's not added

I deleted one table and try to add it again but same issue it's not added, and nothing happened with no error no warning

Tables are only appears in Model.Store

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this problem.

the problem was in one of tables in the database. it's not new table it was already added to the model. the primary key of this table is number and it's matching the foreign key but there is a little difference in (**precision**) it was **3** in primary key and 0 in the foreign key